# latitude more than 65: Error value should not be infinite or NaN, using adhan package

Tags: android, flutter, dart

latitude values between (-67.5944046 and -90) and between (65.9277379 and 90)
throw Unhandled exception!

minimum code that reproduce the error:

```
import 'package:adhan/adhan.dart';

void main() {

//latitude values between (-67.5944046 and -90) and between (65.9277379 and 90)
//throw Unhandled exception!

// var prayerTimes = PrayerTimes(Coordinates(-67.5944046, 120),
// DateComponents.from(DateTime.now()), CalculationMethod.umm_al_qura.getParameters());
var prayerTimes = PrayerTimes(Coordinates(65.9277379, 120),
DateComponents.from(DateTime.now()), CalculationMethod.umm_al_qura.getParameters());
print(prayerTimes.fajr);
}
```

Expected behavior
should output the actual prayer time of the giving parameters.

but it throws an error:

```
C:/Flutter_SDK/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart.exe --enable-asserts "E:\Flutter_UI\hij_greg_temp - Copy\lib\main.dart"
Unhandled exception:
Invalid argument(s): value should not be infinite or NaN
#0 TimeComponents.fromDouble (package:adhan/src/data/time_components.dart:12:7)
#1 new PrayerTimes._ (package:adhan/src/prayer_times.dart:133:37)
#2 new PrayerTimes (package:adhan/src/prayer_times.dart:53:24)
#3 main (package:hij_greg_temp/main.dart:10:21)
#4 _delayEntrypointInvocation. (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:297:19)
#5 _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:12)

Process finished with exit code 255
```

run flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, 3.1.0-9.0.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1766], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 16.11.1)
X Visual Studio is missing necessary components. Please re-run the Visual Studio installer for the "Desktop development with C++" workload, and include these components:
MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools
- If there are multiple build tool versions available, install the latest
C++ CMake tools for Windows
Windows 10 SDK
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.68.1)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

---

Adhan-Dart Version: [adhan: ^2.0.0-nullsafety.2]

Note:
a previous version (adhan: ^1.1.14) was work fine, but i cannot use it anymore because it doesn't provide nullsafety.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the **validate** parameters as false as per their documents like this

```
var prayerTimes = PrayerTimes(Coordinates(65.9277379, 120, validate: false),
        DateComponents.from(DateTime.now()), CalculationMethod.umm_al_qura.getParameters());
```

Or pull the source code from the repo, add null safety yourself in the library code, and give the merge request. Once the developer accepts you can use it with no issues.

Comment: the default value of 'validate' is already = false. I try to change it to true, but it threw the same exception.  for the second option, could you tell me please what you mean? because i did not do that before.

Comment: as you said version 1.1.14 works fine except for null safety, download that version and you add null safety by yourself and use it.

Comment: The actual problem lies in the plugin. On inspecting the calculations were gone wrong marginally. acos for -1.00000008 is being calculated which is impossible to do. So you are getting the error.

Comment: you should raise an issue on GitHub. That will help.

Comment: I trace the error and I found it with the line: final H0 = degrees(acos(term1 / term2)); as you said, it return NaN when latitude has the values that i specified in the issue. However I tried to run the previous version with: flutter run --no-sound-null-safety. It worked it also gave a null but i was handling this error with try and catch so i didn't noticed it. Anyway thank you for helping and yes i already raised the issues on GitHub.

Comment: I tried to solve it in the plugin by checking the value passed to acos function:
if it is less than -1, assign -1 to the value
if it is greater than 1, assign 1 to the value.
the exception is gone and it worked as expected, but i am not sure if the time given is correct or not?

Comment: glad, I have already given a merge request in the repository fixing the issue. I also responded to your GitHub issue. Happy coding